# Грань использования SFINAE

Tags: c++

Часто вижу примеры SFINAE в поиске метода в классе или проверка на наследование, чтобы определить на этапе компиляции ошибку. Но эти же вещи "слетят" при компиляции и без SFINAE и будет ошибка компиляции.

Если не учитывать ситуацию, когда на этапе компиляции отбрасывается не нужный претендент класса и вся эта магия (потому, что я считаю эту часть SFINAE действительно полезной). Зачем используют SFINAE для всяких проверок: есть ли метод, есть ли enum, есть ли конструктор, который принимает строку? Только для связки с той магией?

Comment: Без конкретного примера, сложно что-то говорить. В общем и целом, если есть проверка наличия метода, к примеру, есть ли метод `sort` у класса, если есть — вызываем его, в противном случае вызываем `std::sort`, т.е мы улучшаем использование класса. Вариантов масса, всех не перечесть. Если есть конкретный пример — выкладывайте, иначе разговор будет весьма абстрактный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько мне кажется, смысл проверки — получить ошибку *быстро* и *в нужном месте* — раз, и перенести проверку из уровня синтаксиса в уровень семантики — два.

Смотрите. Если мы, например, для нашего шаблона проверяем наличие в классе `T` конструктора копирования, но пользуемся этим конструктором реально лишь в одном методе внутри, это значит, что ошибка будет найдена не в том месте, где мы определяем шаблон, а позже, при попытке использовать этот самый метод. И сообщение об ошибке будет в терминах внутренностей нашего шаблона, а не в терминах вашего класса.

Есть?

Затем, если какая-то штука *компилируется*, это ещё не значит, что она *правильна*. Например, один и тот же код может иметь смысл только для указателей, но в принципе компилироваться и для `int`'ов. Если использование шаблона с `int`'ом не имеет смысла, лучше не позволять юзеру писать бессмысленный код, а как можно скорее проинформировать его об этом.

---

(Надеюсь, я правильно понял смысл вашего вопроса.)

Comment: да примерно правильно поняли вопрос. Получается: 1) указать место ошибка; 2) ошибки не будет если метод не используется, а SFINAE зарание запретит совершить ошибку.

Comment: @rikimaru2013: Угу, вроде того. Плюс вторая часть про то, что даже если что-то скомпилировалось, оно ещё не обязательно правильно, и если есть возможность выявить ошибку использования, то хорошо бы так и сделать.

Answer (score 4):

SFINAE означает "неудачная подстановка шаблона - это не ошибка".
И смысл SFINAE как раз в том, чтобы не было ошибки компиляции.

SFINAE нужно для того, чтобы убрать из списка перегрузки тот или иной шаблон функции, чтобы вместо него использовалась другая перегрузка функции, например:

```
// Для POD типов
template<typename T>
void clear(T& t, std::enable_if_t<std::is_pod<T>::value>* = 0) {
  std::memset(&t, 0, sizeof(t));
}

// Для не-POD типов
template<typename T>
void clear(T& t, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pod<T>::value>* = 0) {
  t = T{};
}
```

В данном примере, без SFINAE не было бы никакой ошибки компиляции:

```
template<typename T>
void clear(T& t) {
  std::memset(&t, 0, sizeof(t)); // потенциальное UB
}
```

Если перегрузка функции одна, и нужна просто проверка времени компиляции, то вместо SFINAE надо использовать `static_assert`:

```
template<typename T>
void clear_pod(T& t) {
  static_assert(std::is_pod<T>::value, "T must be POD");
  std::memset(&t, 0, sizeof(t));
}
```